# Can there be ordinals larger than those contained in Ord, and if so, can they be used to extend the constructible universe $L$?

Tags: set-theory, constructibility

Can there be ordinals larger than those contained in Ord, the class of all ordinals,and if so, can these ordinals be used to extend the constructible universe $L$?

In a simplified form, my question is (see last paragraph below):  *Given the constructible universe $L$, does there exist a top-extension $N$ of $L$ such that $N$ also satisfies the Axiom of Constructibility?*

To show that the possibility might exist,consider the model $M[H]$ of $ZFC^{-}$ that collapses all sets to be countable. Regarding this model, Andreas Blass writes to Noah S in the comments to mathoverflow question "[How can I collapse all cardinals of the ground model except one of them](https://mathoverflow.net/a/153236)", the following:

"...If I were to think about $M[H]$, I'd pretend that some more powerful set theorists have continued the cumulative hierarchy beyond the hierarchy I see, so that what I think is Ord is actually just some inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$.  Then what I call $M[H]$ is, for people in that bigger universe, the result of Levy collapsing below $\kappa$ and and them truncating the universe at $\kappa$.  That Levy model is pretty well understood, since it occurs along the way in Solovay's construction of his Lebesgue measure model."

This sounds very similar to some ideas of W.N. Reinhardt found in his paper "[Set existence principles of Shoenfield, Ackerman, and Powell](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-article-fmv84i1p2bwm)" (Fundamenta Mathematicae, vol. 84 (1974), pp. 5-34). Let me quote Shoenfield's principle as given to Reinhardt through private communication (found on page 6 of the paper):

"If $\mathtt C$ is a collection of stages [say $\{V_{\alpha\in Ord}\}$—my comment], and if we can imagine a situation in which all of the stages in $\mathtt C$ have been completed, then there is to be a stage $\mathtt S$ after all the stages in $\mathtt C$."   In the comment by Blass to Noah S, the terms "see" and "think" can be fairly deemed to be synonymous with Shoenfield's term "imagine".

Assuming that the stages $L_{\alpha}$ of the 'usual' constructible universe $L$ range over Ord, how does the application of Shoenfield's principle to $L$ (i.e. given that if the union of the elements $L_{\alpha}$ of the collection $\mathtt C$ of stages $L_{\alpha\in Ord}$ form $L$, then there is a stage $L_{\mathtt S}$ after all of the stages in $\mathtt C$, where $\mathtt S$ is a 'new ordinal' such that $\mathtt{S} \notin Ord$ and $L_{\mathtt S}$ is the stage where the constructible subsets of $\mathtt S$ are formed) extend the constructible universe, if at all? (Consider $V$ and $L$ to be classes of sets of ordinals to make better sense of the title.)

Perhaps there is a simpler way to phrase the question.  Given two models $M$ and $N$ of ZFC with $Ord(M) \subset Ord(N)$, let $N$ be a Top-extension of $M$ just in case $M$ is a rank initial segment of $N$, that is, $M$ end-extends to $N$ and also all new objects of $N$ have ordinal rank larger than any ordinal in $M$ (this definition comes from Joel David Hamkins, who put it in his answer to mathoverflow question "[Elementary end extension of a countable model for ZF](https://mathoverflow.net/a/91620)").  It should be noted that $M$,$N$ satisfies Shoenfield's principle in that given $M$(which, being a model of ZFC, has its own version of the cumulative hierarchy completed in $M$) there is a stage $\mathtt S$ in $N$ after all the stages in $\mathtt C$, where $\mathtt C$ is the collection of stages in $M$.

Comment: I don't really understand the question - could you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: @Noah S:  I am simply asking if Shoenfield's principle holds, then is $L$, by including the new stage $\mathtt S$, extended by including more 'constructible sets' than $L$ restricted to Ord.  I am using $M$$[$$H$$]$ as an example of Shoenfield's principle, Prof. Blass's comment to you as an argument in favor of this point of view.

Comment: That's what I don't get, really - what do you mean "if Shoenfield's principle holds?" It's not written as a precise mathematical statement, so I'm not sure how I'd distinguish between a structure in which it was true and a structure in which it wasn't. There are a few precise questions here I could imagine being related - "what happens if you try to continue the $L$-construction through class-well-orderings?" is one - but I really don't know what you are asking. As for $M[H]$ (a la Blass), that's just an initial segment of a $ZF$ model; is that all it takes to satisfy Shoenfield's principle?

Comment: @NoahS:  As regards Blass's interpretation (since it seems to become an initial segment of a ZF model by continuing "the cumulative hierarchy beyond the hierarchy that I see, so that what I think is Ord is actually some inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$)--that definitely satisfies Shoenfield's principle.  The idea here is that if $M$$[$$H$$]$ exists by adding ordinals seemingly 'outside' Ord, then Shoenfield's principle holds.  So the question I ask is, if one applies Shoenfield's principle to $L$, what happens?  As regards your question "what happens if you try to continue the $L$-construction

Comment: I'll try one last time: *What do you mean by "applies Shoenfield's principle to $L$"?* Are you asking the following: "Suppose $V\models ZFC+V=L$, $\kappa\in Ord(V)$, and $V_\kappa\models ZFC+V=L$; then what are some ways $V$ and $V_\kappa$ can be different?" Or are you asking, "Given a model $M$ of $ZFC+V=L$, is there another model $N$ such that $M=L_\alpha^N$ for some $\alpha\in N$?" Or what? I'm not being deliberately slow, I honestly don't know precisely what you are asking; and with this sort of question, precision is really important.

Comment: (cont.) through class-well-orderings" since Ord is a well-ordered class--that satisfies Shoenfield's principle, too.  It's too bad that I can't delete the question, rework it, and then undelete it--if one could one would not be penalized.

Comment: @NoahS:  Perhaps this will help.  Consider two universes $V$ and $U$ with $Ord$$($$V$$)$$\subset$$Ord$$($$U$$)$, both satisfying ZFC+The Axiom of Constructibility.  Question:  Does $U$ have more constructible sets than $V$, and if so, what are the 'new' constructible sets in $U$?

Comment: Ah! This makes more sense. Presumably other people will have more to say about it, but let me just direct you to a beautiful theorem of Barwise that says that *any* model of $ZFC$ has an end extension which is a model of $V=L$. So in principal, *any* model arises as part of the constructible universe of another model. Of course, the models Barwise's theorem produces are not well-founded, so their "ordinals" aren't, really; but it's still interesting. You might also find this question of mine relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/171703/when-is-a-l-ish-whenever-b-is-l-ish

Comment: Re "It's too bad that I can't delete the question, rework it, and then undelete it": Actually, I think you can.  I know that you can do this with answers, and so I assume it is also possible with questions.  Even if you can't, you can always delete it, rework it, and then post a new improved version.

Comment: @EricWofsey:  I myself tried to do this with both questions and answers, i.e. deleted the questions and answers then tried to edit the deleted questions but the system would not let me do this.  How do you go about deleting a question and answer and then edit them?  Can you request a moratorium on people voting on a question or answer until you have fixed it to your satisfaction or to community satisfaction (i.e. have the members of the community act as referees)?  By the way, have you any idea why folks want to close this question?

Comment: Dear @Thomas Benjamin, this question currently has two votes to close as "unclear what you are asking". It may be a good idea for you to edit this question to clarify its meaning, without relying on the comments.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade:  I have attempted to revise the question to make clear what I am asking.  In your opinion, is it still unclear?  If so, please specify what its still unclear so that I might continue to revise.

Comment: @NoahS:  I looked at your question and found it, the answers, and comments very relevant to my question, especially Prof. Hamkins' comments on end- extensions, top-extensions (especially--I think Shoenfield's principle is a statement about top-extensions), and his comment about forcing extensions. Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: @To Those Who Wish To Close This Question:  It is 1:46AM where I am at.  Please be so kind as to state your concerns so I will be able to re-edit this question in order to adequately address them later today when I have time.  Until then, good night.

Comment: I posted to meta here: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2029/2926

Comment: @Francois:  Thank you for editing my question and adding the links.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin: I hope you don't mind my editing. For the sake of those TL;DR-inclined, I moved your simplified question from the bottom of the post to near the top, where it would be more visible.

Comment: There are a few things one can say in answer to this question. For example, from any model of KM+, one can build a model of ZFC- on top. There are some omega_1-like models of V=L that have no elementary top-extensions.

Comment: @WillieWong: If it helps re-open this question, its OK with me.  Thanks.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins:   Can you provide the cites for the theorems and requisite proofs of these claims--I'd be interested in taking a look at them.